# VBA call a SUB in a Sheet from module

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a Sub I defined inside a Sheet, from a Module.

The code I use in my Module (which happens to be inside a Sub):

```
CallByName Worksheets("Sheet_name"), "Sub_name", vbMethod
```

But Excel does not execute the Sub. The Module and Sheet are inside the same workbook.

Comment: Try `Call Worksheets("Sheet_name").Sub_name`

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: works like a charm, tanks you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set your function to `Public` as shown below

Sheet1:

```
Public Sub test()
    MsgBox "Got here!"
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub callTest()
    With Sheet1
        Call .test
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

for me, I had to change the Sheet Sub Procedure from Private to Public for the Call to work.

```
Call Worksheets("Sheet_name").Sub_name
```

In my case:

```
Call Worksheets("Sheet 20").CommandButton1_Click
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's in the same project and of `Public` scope - just use the name of the sub.

If it's in a another workbook, use [`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx)

**1.**

```
Sub Foo()
    Bar '// Runs Sub Bar()
End Sub

Sub Bar()
    MsgBox "I got called!"
End Sub
```

---

**2.**

```
Sub Foo()
    Application.Run "MyOtherWorkbook.xlsm!Bar"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

From any module or sheet (that has a code), 
if you have a sub called `Button1_click()` in "`Sheet12`" and you want to call it from other module or sheet.
just type

```
call Sheets("Sheet12").Button1_click 'Without parenthesis
```